# What is the fastest way to calculate PRAUC-PRAUC / Precision-Recall Area Under the Curve?

Tags: r

I'm trying to search for a package that is similar to ROCAUC calculations but that are more efficient in the PRAUC. For reference I am trying to compute about 13 million rows in under 1 second. With ROCAUC the fastest I've come across is bigstatsr which was able to calculate the ROCAUC in around 2 seconds.

I've tried looking around for packages and the fastest I've come across is 'precrec' - which was able to calculate both the ROCAUC and PRAUC in under 5 seconds

All the common options I've seen are too slow for my use case - https://cran.r-hub.io/web/packages/WeightedROC/vignettes/Speed.pdf

I'd appreciate any help

Looking through packages there seems to be few that fit my use case or I have considered it might be better to write a custom function.

Here is an example of what I'm trying to achieve

```
#Precrec only example

library(tidyverse)
library(precrec)
library(data.table)

#Initializing alphas
prealpha <- data.frame(row = 1:1001, Alpha1 = seq(0,1,by=0.001))
alpha <- prealpha %>%
  slice(rep(1:n(), each = nrow(prealpha))) %>%
  group_by(row) %>%
  mutate(Alpha2 = seq(0,1,by=0.001)) %>%
  mutate(Alpha3 = 1 - (Alpha1+Alpha2)) %>%
  filter(if_any(Alpha3,~.>=0))
alpha$row <- seq_len(nrow(alpha))
rm(prealpha)
alpha$row <- NULL
alpha <- as.data.frame(alpha)

m <- matrix(15:1, nrow = 13000000, ncol = 3) #Initalizing test list

#Everything below would be the for loop, where p = as.matrix(alpha[i,])

p <- as.matrix(alpha[1,]) #extacting 1 row from alpha list
p <- as.vector(p)

s <- m^matrix(p,nrow(m),ncol(m), byrow = TRUE) #multiplying by single alpha row
s2 <- s[,1] * s[,2] * s[,3] #multiplying columns together
ForAUC <- cbind(s2,c(1:0)) #pulling back reference values for ROC calculating check

ForAUC <- as.data.table(ForAUC)

sscurves <- evalmod(scores = ForAUC$s2, labels = ForAUC$V2)
aucss <- auc(sscurves) 
#Would be put into a 'results', with results[[i]] <- aucss
```

Comment: I don't have any data handy to test it, but one potential option is [yardstick](https://yardstick.tidymodels.org/index.html) - how does that go with your ~13M rows?

Comment: I have not. I am unfamiliar with the method they want to coax the data into the appropriate commands. I'll have to take a further look into other discussions because I am not quite sure as to how I should restructure my current data.frame with predictions and true values.

Comment: @jared_mamrot It's a piecemealed iterative calculation based on fluctuating alpha values. I have updated the post accordingly.

Comment: @jared_mamrot Ah yes, my apologies. 'm' in this case is equal to the declared 'List' variables. I have made the adjustment accordingly to have m  unified in place.

Comment: I tried yardstick but it was slower that precrec on my system using your example data (~7s vs ~5s; `yardstick::roc_auc_vec(estimate = ForAUC$s2, truth = factor(ForAUC$V2))`). I'm not really sure what you're trying to do or why you're trying to do it, but I suspect you'll need to change to a vectorized function or switch languages to get <1s, like C++ (e.g. https://github.com/liurui39660/AUROC via Rcpp) or python (e.g. https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.roc_auc_score.html). I'll put a bounty on the question and we'll see what other suggestions people have

Comment: I'm trying to calculate both the AUROC/AUPRC for all values in the table "alpha". In terms of looping every row of my alpha table and then calculating the AUCs from each. Other words, multiplying my 'm' table by each row in alpha. Why? I'm trying to find the best row of  'alpha' that returns the highest AUC-ROC/PR. I'm trying to minimize the time to process before parallelization. I'm limited by my knowledge of how vectorized functions may help this problem. I was initially trying to find a better package than precrec but this post may turn into a better way to approach my problem. Thank you